# How to rename igraph node id when writing to file

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to write a graph to a file but I'm getting a different node labels than I would like.

**Example Code:**

```
g <- graph.star(2)
V(g)$name <- c('homer','marge')
write.graph(g,file = 'g.graphml',format = 'graphml')
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
         http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
<!-- Created by igraph -->
  <key id="g_name" for="graph" attr.name="name" attr.type="string"/>
  <key id="g_mode" for="graph" attr.name="mode" attr.type="string"/>
  <key id="g_center" for="graph" attr.name="center" attr.type="double"/>
  <key id="v_name" for="node" attr.name="name" attr.type="string"/>
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
    <data key="g_name">In-star</data>
    <data key="g_mode">in</data>
    <data key="g_center">1</data>
    <node id="n0">                      ###### This should <node id = "homer">
      <data key="v_name">homer</data>
     </node>
     <node id="n1">                     ###### This should <node id = "marge">
      <data key="v_name">marge</data>
     </node>
     <edge source="n1" target="n0"> 
     </edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

I would like the "node id" attribute to be the names of the nodes (as shown in comments). Anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK the "node ID" attribute cannot be the name of the node because there is no guarantee that the IDs you supply are suitable IDs in the GraphML format. The GraphML DTD specifies type `#IDREF` for the `id` attribute, and certain characters are disallowed in `#IDREF`s in an XML file.

Comment: OK, thanks! I saw the comment on the GitHub issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this currently AFAIK. I am not sure why it is not implemented that way. Can you please open an issue about it at https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues?state=open ? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Gabor, Thanks for the quick reply. I'll open an issue as requested. Thanks for the awesome package btw :)

Comment: Has the issue been soved at the end? Because I'm having the same malfunctioning behaviour right now.